# ¿Qué significa un TypeError en mi código?

Tags: python

Aquí esta el código para que puedan verlo:

```
***print('************************CALCULADORA**********************')
class Calculadora:
    def __init__(self, numero1, numero2, ):
        self.numero1 = numero1
        self.numero2 = numero2
    
         
    def suma(self, numero1, numero2):
        return numero1 + numero2
    
    
    
    def resta(self, numero1, numero2):
        return numero1 - numero2
    
    def producto(self, numero1, numero2):
        return numero1 * numero2
    
    
    
    def division(self, numero1, numero2):
        return numero1 / numero2
       
print('Calculadora en PYTHON')
print()
num1 = int(input("Ingrese el primer número: "))
num2 = int(input('Ingrese el segundo número: '))
print()
print()
print()
print()
calculo1 = Calculadora(num1, num2)
print('CALCULO 1 (con el primer y segundo número)')
print()
print()
print()
print('La suma es:', calculo1.suma(num1,num2))
print('La resta es:', calculo1.resta(num1,num2))
print('La multiplicación es:', calculo1.producto(calculo1))
print('La división es:', calculo1.división(num1,num2))***
```

Me aparece:

```
print('La multiplicación es:', calculo1.producto(calculo1))
TypeError: producto() missing 1 required positional argument: 'numero2'
```

No sé que esta mal, se lo agradeceria mucho al que me ayude.

Comment: La función `producto` está definida con dos parámetros (numero1 y numero2). Tú la llamas con sólo uno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta línea de código:

```
print('La multiplicación es:', calculo1.producto(calculo1))
```

la deberías tener como:

```
print('La multiplicación es:', calculo1.producto(num1,num2))
```

Comment: Gracias enserio, pero ahora tambien me sale que AttributeError: 'Calculadora' object has no attribute 'división' que deberia hacer

Comment: @SJP. `division` está definida sin acento; tú la llamas con acento `división`.

Comment: Gracias mil, no se que hubiera hecho sin su ayuda

Comment: Por nada amigo, para servirte